# Compress PDF files with GUI app for linux

Tags: xubuntu

I have searched and researched internet to find a program or app for xubuntu to compress pdf files, but I cannot find, I found a Nautilus script to do that but I don't know if it works in xubuntu with Thunar file manager.I'm looking for a GUI program, can some one help me??Thanks Vladimir

Comment: Have you tried LibreOffice Draw?  You can open PDF files with it and then export as PDF.  You can change the DPI settings when exporting to make the file smaller, but you'll be sacrificing image quality.

Comment: @Dorian I'm look for a GUI app for linux, I think libreoffice draw cannot compress a bulk files of PDF at the same time.

Comment: Oh, no LibreOffice Draw can't do bulk files, only one at a time.  There's something called ghostscript that I've seen.  Never used it before but it's supposed to be able to compress PDF files, and you should be able to do entire directories at a time.

Comment: @Dorian I know, there is ghostscript, but this is CLI and I'm looking for a program with GUI, is there ghostscript with GUI??

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.